# How to find the least positive root?

Tags: numerical-methods

How to numerically find the least positive root of equation?

What numerical method should I use and with what starting conditions?

I believe I don't have all the roots to be sure, do I?

Although answer to general case would be nice, I would also add that I'm solving quartic equations.

Comment: Roots to quartic equations can be found exactly - check the wikipedia page for details. For more general equations you could probably use Newton's method, but without more details it's difficult to say anything specific.

Comment: [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) might be a handy tool too. You can get pretty accurate approximations of roots by just typing your equation.